# Toggle between Divs containing classes

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

How would I simply replace `<div class="one">` with the following `<div class="two">` when I hover over it and vice versa? (`<div class="two">` will be replaced with `<div class="one">` on mouseleave)

Here is the markup:

```
<div class="one">content1</div>
<div class="two">content2</div>

<div class="one">content3</div>
<div class="two">content4</div>

<div class="one">content5</div>
<div class="two">content6</div>, etc....
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this OK? http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/vjxBK/2/

```
$('div.one').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).hide().next().show();
});

$('div.two').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).hide().prev().show();    
}
```

Note that in order for this solution to work, the `.one` and `.two` DIV pairs have to have equal heights. Otherwise the cursor might not be over the `.two` element once `.one` is hidden in which case the mouseleave event would not fire.

Comment: The moddle of SO is to post the answer. Otherwise the solution is blind to the data dumps or lost if jsfiddle goes down.

Comment: Great! This worked. I was working with .find and forgot about next() and prev(). Thanks and thanks to everybody on this Saturday evening!

Comment: I spelled "model" as "moddle" and didn't think twice, and I wasn't even drinking.

Comment: @Stefan Yea, I noticed that word, but I'm not a native speaker so I thought it's just some fancy word that I still haven't heard of `:)`

Answer (score 0):

If you hover over div one, and then let it disappear, you're not hovering over it anymore. I'd suggest html like this for instance:

```
<div class="outer"><span class="first">content1<span>
<div class="inner">content2</div>
</div>
```

And then in css something like:

```
.outer .first {display: block;}
.outer .inner {display: none ;}

.outer:hover .first {display: none;}
.outer:hover .inner {display: block ;}
```

Comment: If you want to support this in IE8, you need to do this with jQuery.

Comment: It actually does since IE7, as long as you use strict, and don't let IE kick into quirks mode.
http://www.bernzilla.com/item.php?id=762

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
   $(".one").hover(
        function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("two","one");
        },
        function(){    
            $(this).toggleClass("two","one");
        }
    );
```